# Where to store data used in different Android activities?

Tags: android

In my application, I have one activity, which connects to the server and gets certain user information from it. Then, it launches another activity where that information should be processed.

What is the correct way to pass data between activities in Android?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If that data is only needed once, you should use an [`Intent`](https://developer.android.com/index.html#q=Intent). [Here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidIntent/article.html) is a tutorial on it.

If it needs to be accessed all the time, you can put it in an [`Application`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) subclass or some other singleton.

In general you can use methods like [`putExtra`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra%28java.lang.String,%20float%29), to attach data to an Intent, and then use 
for example `getIntent().getStringExtra(name)` to retrieve it in the other activity.

---